# Inflating a custom layout view into a Layout extending class in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I have a custom layout defined in XML file which has a RelativeLayout root with a bunch of child view.

Now, I defined the following class:

```
public class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();     
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        Log.d("Widget", "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
        Log.d("Widget", "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

        int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
    }

    private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
        if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            return size;
        } else { 
            return getPreferredSize();
        }
    }

    private int getPreferredSize() {
        return 400;
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm setting the root to `MyCustomView` instance and the attach flag to true.

What I want to achieve is that when I will add this custom view in another layout's xml, it will instantiate the `MyCustomView` class which will have the layout defined in the XML.

I already tries to use `<merge>` tag, but that way I lose the ability to arrange my child views in the XML as I want.

I also tried to inflate the XML and add it as a view to `MyCustomView`, but that way I get redundant `RelativeLayout`.

Last thing, I added the `onMeasure()` just for completeness.

Comment: Your problem is that the views from `R.layout.widget_view` don't appear in the `Widget` component, right?

Comment: Exactly. the inflation occurs but the child view are not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the inflation occurs but the child view are not shown

The `RelativeLayout` does a bit more(a lot) than what you've done in the `onMeasure` layout(basically the children aren't measured at all with your code so they don't have something to show). If you extend a `ViewGroup` like `RelativeLayout` you need to let that class to do its callbacks(`onMeasure`, `onLayout`) or at least, very carefully replicate the methods and modify it like you want (if you want to see something).

So, remove the `onMeasure` method to see the children or explain better why did you override it.

Comment: @Daniel Make sure you removed it completely, it wouldn't hurt if you posted the `my_custom_view` layout file.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! BTW, I added the onMeasure() in order to force that my view width and height will be equal. any idea how can I do that in a different way?